# Expression for Atmospheric Pressure with Altitude, including Tidal Forces

Tags: newtonian-gravity, pressure, atmospheric-science

Is this simple to obtain?  I've tried to modify the constant-gravity model to use the $GM/r^2$ form instead, but my result was shown to be wrong with some testing.

**Constant Gravity Model**

You can find this in many places online.  [Here's one](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap2.html).  I'll repeat that work here, jumping over the calculus, and putting it in terms of Earth's radius.  r0 will be the surface radius.

$$ \frac{ dP }{ dr } \frac{ 1 }{ P(r) } = - \frac{ M_0 g }{ R T }  \\
H \equiv \frac{ R T }{ M_0 g } \approx 7.4 \text{ km} \\
P(r) = P_0 e^{ \frac{ r_0 - r }{ H } }  $$

**Non-constant Gravity Model**

So to generalize this (for a small moon with a diffuse atmosphere, for instance), just replace the gravity with its expression $g(r)=GM/r^2$.  M0 is still the average formula mass of air, but we add M, which is the mass of the planet.  This should work fine for Earth, I see no reason it shouldn't.

$$ \frac{ dP }{ dr } \frac{ 1 }{ P(r) } = - \frac{ M_0 G M }{ R T } \frac{1}{r^2}  \\
H' \equiv \frac{ M_0 G M  }{R T } \approx 4,739 \text{ km} \\
P(r) = P_0 e^{ H' \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_0} \right) }  $$

It looks so nice and congruent.  But I [plot my non-constant gravity model side-by-side with the constant model](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B%20exp%28%286300-r%29/7.4%29%20,%20exp%28%204739%2a%281/r-1/6300%29%29%20%7D%20for%20r%20from%206300%20to%206400) and it's obviously wrong.

So for my question, could somebody do ANY of:

- Find something I did wrong
- Derive or find a correct model for this
- Give a clear reason it can't be obtained in a simple closed form

Answer (score 2):

Wait, don't bother.  I found the embarrassing error.  It's the H' value.  It should have been:

$$ H' \equiv \frac{ M_0 G M  }{R T } \approx 4,739,000 \text{ km} $$

I just read [that output](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2828.97%20grams/mol%29%2aG%2a%28mass%20of%20Earth%29/%28R%2a%28293%20Kelvin%29%29) wrong.  [The plots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logplot%20%7B%20exp%28%286300-r%29/7.4%29%20,%20exp%28%204739e3%2a%281/r-1/6300%29%29%20%7D%20for%20r%20from%206300%20to%206400) now seem to fit.

Sorry to answer my own question so fast.  I suppose whether any of this is right remains an open question.

Comment: You also have to keep in mind that the specific gas constant ($\frac{R}{M_0}$) and temperature will also vary width height. And for a dense enough atmosphere there will also be a significant increase in the gravitational parameter ($GM$) when you go farther away.

Comment: @fibonatic Yes, certainly, I shouldn't have ever implied this actually describes Earth's atmosphere.  The thermosphere parameters conditions are closer to 1 amu and 1000 C, with major effects from weather, time, and geographic location.  I was intending to apply this to the sci-fi concept "shell world", which it would accurately describe.  But while wrong for Earth, it's still formally more accurate than the constant gravity model.

Answer (score 2):

My solution has been challenged, and this comes from a separate source so I'm posting it as community wiki.  The reference is here:

http://web.ist.utl.pt/~berberan/data/43.pdf

The proposed equation is:

$$ P(z) = P(0) \exp{ \left( - \frac{ m g_0 R_0 }{ kT} \frac{ z }{ z+R_0 } \right) }$$

You could put this in terms of characteristic height if you wanted.  The question in my mind is rather this solves the same equation that I was aiming for.

Any insight as to what might be wrong with the differential equation I formulated would be appreciated.

---

Also, their equation references equations 5 and 7 in that paper for a justification of where it comes from.  I'll echo those here.  Equation 5:

$$ p(z) = p(H) + \frac{m}{k} \int_z^H \frac{g p(u) }{ T} du$$

Equation 7:

$$ \frac{dp}{dz} = - \frac{ m g }{ k T } p $$

The idea is that you substitute in $g(z)$ in place of $g$.  Honestly, I think this is what I had.  Their math looks a little different, but it should come out to the same thing.  I don't know what went wrong.

---

I think I've solved it now.  The problem is that the other source uses altitude (z), whereas I have used radius (r).  It also used surface gravity where I used mass and the gravitational constant.  If you just re-write my equations from the OP and make these substitutions, you can match the two expressions.  I have done that here:

$$ z \equiv r_0 + z \\
H' \equiv \frac{ M_0 G M  }{R T } \approx 4,739 \text{ km} \\
P(r) = P_0 e^{ H' \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_0} \right) }  \\
P(z) = P_0 e^{ H' \left( \frac{1}{r_0 + z} - \frac{1}{r_0} \right) }  \\
P(z) = P_0 e^{ - \frac{ H'}{r_0} \frac{ z}{ r_0 + z} } \\
P(z) = P_0 e^{ - \frac{ M_0 G M  }{R T r_0}  \frac{ z}{ r_0 + z} } \\
g_0 \equiv \frac{ G M }{ r_0^2 } \\
P(z) = P_0 \exp{ \left( - \frac{ M_0 g_0 r_0 }{R T }  \frac{ z}{ r_0 + z} \right) } $$

These are, in fact, the same thing.